# ValidationError: is not a valid UUID in Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-2.0

I'm using `Django 2.0`

I have a `Note` table and `StarredNotes` table.

Initially, there was no `id` field as it was added by default by `Django` as `integer` data type.

Now I have changed the data type of `id` to `UUID` in model

**model.py**

```
class Starred(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.ForeignKey(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = StarredManager()

class ColorLabels(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '(' + self.value + ')'
```

and **views.py**

```
class StarredNotes(ListView):
    template_name = 'notes/starred.html'
    model = Starred
    context_object_name = 'starred_notes'

    def get_queryset(self):
        starred_notes = Starred.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-updated')
        return starred_notes

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and **urls.py**

```
app_name = 'notes'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MyNotes.as_view()),
    url(r'^my/$', MyNotes.as_view(), name='my'),
    path('<pk>/', NoteUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('share-public/<pk>/', ShareNotePublic.as_view(), name='share-public'),
    path('starred-notes/', StarredNotes.as_view(), name='starred'),
    path('shared-notes/', SharedNotes.as_view(), name='shared'),
    path('delete/<pk>/', DeleteNote.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('new/', NewNote.as_view(), name='new'),
    path('<pk>/public/', PublicNoteView.as_view(), name='public-view'),
]
```

but when I access the view using

```
http://127.0.0.1:1234/notes/starred-notes/
```

**It gives error as**

```
ValidationError at /notes/starred-notes/

["'starred-notes' is not a valid UUID."]
```

Comment: Can you post full urlpatterns list? Probably you have detail view there right above StarredNotes view, which triggered by `/notes/starred-notes/` url. You need to swap those patterns.

Comment: Also note you must never use `self.__class__` in a super call, if you ever subclass that view you will get an infinite regression.

Comment: updated `urlpatterns`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `path('<pk>/', NoteUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),` pattern is too common and it's intercepts starred-notes url. You need to move it to the bottom of the list or better add uuid converter `path('<uuid:pk>/', NoteUpdate.as_view(), name='update')`.